# .gitignore ignoring a file even though no rules specify it

Tags: git, gitignore

This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
smarty/templates_c
config.codekit
components/**/styles/
components/**/js/
!components/root/js-dev/plugin/select2-4.0.3/dist/js/
!components/root/js-dev/plugin/chartjs/
.sass-cache/
/node_modules/
/dbv-parkrooau/
/pma-parkrooau/
count.php
```

Hence, if I make a change inside of `components/foo/js-dev/main.js`, then `.gitignore` will track its change, and include it in my repository; this is fine.

However, I have a file located at `components/theygo/js-dev/shoppingcart.js` - `.gitignore` does **not** track changes to this file, for a reason that is beyond me. `components/theygo/js-dev/main.js` works fine, as does `components/root/js-dev/main.js`, as does every other JavaScript file I've created so far - just this one file, and I'm not sure why.

If I remove `components/**/js/` from my `.gitignore`, it tracks the file, but also tracks all files in the `js` subdirectory, inside of any directory inside of `components`.

If I add in this line:

```
!components/theygo/js-dev/shoppingcart.js
```

It tracks the file correctly.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and what I can do to best fix this, rather than adding in a dirty inclusion statement?

Comment: Anything in ~/.gitignore_global ? Also you might want to run 'git check-ignore -v components/theygo/js-dev/shoppingcart.js', it ought to tell you which rule cause the ignore.

Comment: @ptyx I tried running that command and it returned nothing.

Comment: If `components/theygo/js-dev/shoppingcart.js` and `components/theygo/js-dev/main.js` are not effected by the rule `components/**/js/` in the same way. I doubt they are not at same path somehow.

Comment: Shot in the dark: do you have another file in the same directory with the same case, on a case insensitive file system? check-ignore empty means file is NOT ignored, so we have an inconsistency in behavior at the very least (I'm assuming that by ".gitignore does not track changes to this file" you mean git-status doesn't show it unless you explicitly 'git add' it?)

Comment: @ptyx No, unfortunately - the only files I have inside that `js-dev` directory are `shoppingcart.js`, `page2.js` and `viewproduct.js`... the other two both work fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First commit and push your all current changes.
Then you have to remove all tracked files and add them back in 
using the below commands

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any .gitignore in you sub-directories?
based on your .gitignore, and I also tried with the exact folder structure, this file will be track properly

Comment: No, no `.gitignore` in any subdirectories, in a way that will impact `shoppingcart.js`, i.e. nothing in `components`, `theygo` nor `js-dev`.